# Not able to see files while opening file browser using AndroidFileBrowser Library

Tags: android, android-intent, file-browser

I am trying to make a File browser for which I am taking help of [this library](https://codeload.github.com/vaal12/AndroidFileBrowser/zip/master).

Now according their code I am trying to implement, it's opening the desired location in the cell, however I am only able to see directories not files. As instructed I have chosen the option to choose Files only still I am not able to see Files there. Below is the code I am using

```
Intent fileExploreIntent = new Intent(FileBrowserActivity.INTENT_ACTION_SELECT_DIR,
                null, getActivity(), FileBrowserActivity.class
                );
                startActivityForResult(fileExploreIntent,1);
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (requestCode == 1) {
            if(resultCode == getActivity().RESULT_OK) {
                String newDir = data.getStringExtra(FileBrowserActivity.returnDirectoryParameter);
                Toast.makeText( getActivity(), "Received path from file browser:"+newDir, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
            } else {//if(resultCode == this.RESULT_OK) {
                Toast.makeText( getActivity(),"Received NO result from file browser",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
            }//END } else {//if(resultCode == this.RESULT_OK) {
        }//if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_PICK_FILE_TO_SAVE_INTERNAL) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

**Code for FileBrowserActivity is**

```
public class FileBrowserActivity extends Activity {
// Intent Action Constants
public static final String INTENT_ACTION_SELECT_DIR = "com.afixi.xmppclientandroid.SELECT_DIRECTORY_ACTION";
public static final String INTENT_ACTION_SELECT_FILE = "com.afixi.xmppclientandroid.SELECT_FILE_ACTION";

// Intent parameters names constants
public static final String startDirectoryParameter = "com.afixi.xmppclientandroid.directoryPath";
public static final String returnDirectoryParameter = "com.afixi.xmppclientandroid.directoryPathRet";
public static final String returnFileParameter = "com.afixi.xmppclientandroid.filePathRet";
public static final String showCannotReadParameter = "com.afixi.xmppclientandroid.showCannotRead";
public static final String filterExtension = "com.afixi.xmppclientandroid.filterExtension";

// Stores names of traversed directories
ArrayList<String> pathDirsList = new ArrayList<String>();

// Check if the first level of the directory structure is the one showing
// private Boolean firstLvl = true;

private static final String LOGTAG = "F_PATH";

private List<Item> fileList = new ArrayList<Item>();
private File path = null;
private String chosenFile;
// private static final int DIALOG_LOAD_FILE = 1000;

ArrayAdapter<Item> adapter;

private boolean showHiddenFilesAndDirs = true;

private boolean directoryShownIsEmpty = false;

private String filterFileExtension = null;

// Action constants
private static int currentAction = -1;
private static final int SELECT_DIRECTORY = 1;
private static final int SELECT_FILE = 2;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // In case of
    // ua.com.vassiliev.androidfilebrowser.SELECT_DIRECTORY_ACTION
    // Expects com.mburman.fileexplore.directoryPath parameter to
    // point to the start folder.
    // If empty or null, will start from SDcard root.
    setContentView(R.layout.ua_com_vassiliev_filebrowser_layout);

    // Set action for this activity
    Intent thisInt = this.getIntent();
    currentAction = SELECT_DIRECTORY;// This would be a default action in
                                        // case not set by intent
    if (thisInt.getAction().equalsIgnoreCase(INTENT_ACTION_SELECT_FILE)) {
        Log.d(LOGTAG, "SELECT ACTION - SELECT FILE");
        currentAction = SELECT_FILE;
    }

    showHiddenFilesAndDirs = thisInt.getBooleanExtra(
            showCannotReadParameter, true);

    filterFileExtension = thisInt.getStringExtra(filterExtension);

    setInitialDirectory();

    parseDirectoryPath();
    loadFileList();
    this.createFileListAdapter();
    this.initializeButtons();
    this.initializeFileListView();
    updateCurrentDirectoryTextView();
    Log.d(LOGTAG, path.getAbsolutePath());
}

private void setInitialDirectory() {
    Intent thisInt = this.getIntent();
    String requestedStartDir = thisInt
            .getStringExtra(startDirectoryParameter);

    if (requestedStartDir != null && requestedStartDir.length() > 0) {// if(requestedStartDir!=null
        File tempFile = new File(requestedStartDir);
        if (tempFile.isDirectory())
            this.path = tempFile;
    }// if(requestedStartDir!=null

    if (this.path == null) {// No or invalid directory supplied in intent
                            // parameter
        if (Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().isDirectory()
                && Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().canRead())
            path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        else
            path = new File("/");
    }// if(this.path==null) {//No or invalid directory supplied in intent
        // parameter
}// private void setInitialDirectory() {

private void parseDirectoryPath() {
    pathDirsList.clear();
    String pathString = path.getAbsolutePath();
    String[] parts = pathString.split("/");
    int i = 0;
    while (i < parts.length) {
        pathDirsList.add(parts[i]);
        i++;
    }
}

private void initializeButtons() {
    Button upDirButton = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.upDirectoryButton);
    upDirButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d(LOGTAG, "onclick for upDirButton");
            loadDirectoryUp();
            loadFileList();
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            updateCurrentDirectoryTextView();
        }
    });// upDirButton.setOnClickListener(

    Button selectFolderButton = (Button) this
            .findViewById(R.id.selectCurrentDirectoryButton);
    if (currentAction == SELECT_DIRECTORY) {
        selectFolderButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d(LOGTAG, "onclick for selectFolderButton");
                returnDirectoryFinishActivity();
            }
        });
    } else {// if(currentAction == this.SELECT_DIRECTORY) {
        selectFolderButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }// } else {//if(currentAction == this.SELECT_DIRECTORY) {
}// private void initializeButtons() {

private void loadDirectoryUp() {
    // present directory removed from list
    String s = pathDirsList.remove(pathDirsList.size() - 1);
    // path modified to exclude present directory
    path = new File(path.toString().substring(0,
            path.toString().lastIndexOf(s)));
    fileList.clear();
}

private void updateCurrentDirectoryTextView() {
    int i = 0;
    String curDirString = "";
    while (i < pathDirsList.size()) {
        curDirString += pathDirsList.get(i) + "/";
        i++;
    }
    if (pathDirsList.size() == 0) {
        ((Button) this.findViewById(R.id.upDirectoryButton))
                .setEnabled(false);
        curDirString = "/";
    } else
        ((Button) this.findViewById(R.id.upDirectoryButton))
                .setEnabled(true);
    long freeSpace = getFreeSpace(curDirString);
    String formattedSpaceString = formatBytes(freeSpace);
    if (freeSpace == 0) {
        Log.d(LOGTAG, "NO FREE SPACE");
        File currentDir = new File(curDirString);
        if(!currentDir.canWrite())
            formattedSpaceString = "NON Writable";
    }

    ((Button) this.findViewById(R.id.selectCurrentDirectoryButton))
            .setText("Select\n[" + formattedSpaceString
                    + "]");

    ((TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.currentDirectoryTextView))
            .setText("Current directory: " + curDirString);
}// END private void updateCurrentDirectoryTextView() {

private void showToast(String message) {
    Toast.makeText(this, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

private void initializeFileListView() {
    ListView lView = (ListView) this.findViewById(R.id.fileListView);
    lView.setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams lParam = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
    lParam.setMargins(15, 5, 15, 5);
    lView.setAdapter(this.adapter);
    lView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            chosenFile = fileList.get(position).file;
            File sel = new File(path + "/" + chosenFile);
            Log.d(LOGTAG, "Clicked:" + chosenFile);
            if (sel.isDirectory()) {
                if (sel.canRead()) {
                    // Adds chosen directory to list
                    pathDirsList.add(chosenFile);
                    path = new File(sel + "");
                    Log.d(LOGTAG, "Just reloading the list");
                    loadFileList();
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    updateCurrentDirectoryTextView();
                    Log.d(LOGTAG, path.getAbsolutePath());
                } else {// if(sel.canRead()) {
                    showToast("Path does not exist or cannot be read");
                }// } else {//if(sel.canRead()) {
            }// if (sel.isDirectory()) {
                // File picked or an empty directory message clicked
            else {// if (sel.isDirectory()) {
                Log.d(LOGTAG, "item clicked");
                if (!directoryShownIsEmpty) {
                    Log.d(LOGTAG, "File selected:" + chosenFile);
                    returnFileFinishActivity(sel.getAbsolutePath());
                }
            }// else {//if (sel.isDirectory()) {
        }// public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
    });// lView.setOnClickListener(
}// private void initializeFileListView() {

private void returnDirectoryFinishActivity() {
    Intent retIntent = new Intent();
    retIntent.putExtra(returnDirectoryParameter, path.getAbsolutePath());
    this.setResult(RESULT_OK, retIntent);
    this.finish();
}// END private void returnDirectoryFinishActivity() {

private void returnFileFinishActivity(String filePath) {
    Intent retIntent = new Intent();
    retIntent.putExtra(returnFileParameter, filePath);
    this.setResult(RESULT_OK, retIntent);
    this.finish();
}// END private void returnDirectoryFinishActivity() {

private void loadFileList() {
    try {
        path.mkdirs();
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        Log.e(LOGTAG, "unable to write on the sd card ");
    }
    fileList.clear();

    if (path.exists() && path.canRead()) {
        FilenameFilter filter = new FilenameFilter() {
            public boolean accept(File dir, String filename) {
                File sel = new File(dir, filename);
                boolean showReadableFile = showHiddenFilesAndDirs
                        || sel.canRead();
                // Filters based on whether the file is hidden or not
                if (currentAction == SELECT_DIRECTORY) {
                    return (sel.isDirectory() && showReadableFile);
                }
                if (currentAction == SELECT_FILE) {

                    // If it is a file check the extension if provided
                    if (sel.isFile() && filterFileExtension != null) {
                        return (showReadableFile && sel.getName().endsWith(
                                filterFileExtension));
                    }
                    return (showReadableFile);
                }
                return true;
            }// public boolean accept(File dir, String filename) {
        };// FilenameFilter filter = new FilenameFilter() {

        String[] fList = path.list(filter);
        this.directoryShownIsEmpty = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < fList.length; i++) {
            // Convert into file path
            File sel = new File(path, fList[i]);
            Log.d(LOGTAG,
                    "File:" + fList[i] + " readable:"
                            + (Boolean.valueOf(sel.canRead())).toString());
            int drawableID = R.drawable.file_icon;
            boolean canRead = sel.canRead();
            // Set drawables
            if (sel.isDirectory()) {
                if (canRead) {
                    drawableID = R.drawable.folder_icon;
                } else {
                    drawableID = R.drawable.folder_icon_light;
                }
            }
            fileList.add(i, new Item(fList[i], drawableID, canRead));
        }// for (int i = 0; i < fList.length; i++) {
        if (fileList.size() == 0) {
            // Log.d(LOGTAG, "This directory is empty");
            this.directoryShownIsEmpty = true;
            fileList.add(0, new Item("Directory is empty", -1, true));
        } else {// sort non empty list
            Collections.sort(fileList, new ItemFileNameComparator());
        }
    } else {
        Log.e(LOGTAG, "path does not exist or cannot be read");
    }
    // Log.d(TAG, "loadFileList finished");
}// private void loadFileList() {

private void createFileListAdapter() {
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Item>(this,
            android.R.layout.select_dialog_item, android.R.id.text1,
            fileList) {
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            // creates view
            View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
            TextView textView = (TextView) view
                    .findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
            // put the image on the text view
            int drawableID = 0;
            if (fileList.get(position).icon != -1) {
                // If icon == -1, then directory is empty
                drawableID = fileList.get(position).icon;
            }
            textView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(drawableID, 0,
                    0, 0);

            textView.setEllipsize(null);

            // add margin between image and text (support various screen
            // densities)
            // int dp5 = (int) (5 *
            // getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density + 0.5f);
            int dp3 = (int) (3 * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density + 0.5f);
            // TODO: change next line for empty directory, so text will be
            // centered
            textView.setCompoundDrawablePadding(dp3);
            textView.setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY);
            return view;
        }// public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup
    };// adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Item>(this,
}// private createFileListAdapter(){

private class Item {
    public String file;
    public int icon;
    public boolean canRead;

    public Item(String file, Integer icon, boolean canRead) {
        this.file = file;
        this.icon = icon;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return file;
    }
}// END private class Item {

private class ItemFileNameComparator implements Comparator<Item> {
    public int compare(Item lhs, Item rhs) {
        return lhs.file.toLowerCase().compareTo(rhs.file.toLowerCase());
    }
}

public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
        Log.d(LOGTAG, "ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE");
    } else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
        Log.d(LOGTAG, "ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT");
    }
    // Layout apparently changes itself, only have to provide good onMeasure
    // in custom components
    // TODO: check with keyboard
    // if(newConfig.keyboard == Configuration.KEYBOARDHIDDEN_YES)
}// END public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {

public static long getFreeSpace(String path) {
    StatFs stat = new StatFs(path);
    long availSize = (long) stat.getAvailableBlocks()
            * (long) stat.getBlockSize();
    return availSize;
}// END public static long getFreeSpace(String path) {

public static String formatBytes(long bytes) {
    // TODO: add flag to which part is needed (e.g. GB, MB, KB or bytes)
    String retStr = "";
    // One binary gigabyte equals 1,073,741,824 bytes.
    if (bytes > 1073741824) {// Add GB
        long gbs = bytes / 1073741824;
        retStr += (new Long(gbs)).toString() + "GB ";
        bytes = bytes - (gbs * 1073741824);
    }
    // One MB - 1048576 bytes
    if (bytes > 1048576) {// Add GB
        long mbs = bytes / 1048576;
        retStr += (new Long(mbs)).toString() + "MB ";
        bytes = bytes - (mbs * 1048576);
    }
    if (bytes > 1024) {
        long kbs = bytes / 1024;
        retStr += (new Long(kbs)).toString() + "KB";
        bytes = bytes - (kbs * 1024);
    } else
        retStr += (new Long(bytes)).toString() + " bytes";
    return retStr;
}// public static String formatBytes(long bytes){

}// END public class FileBrowserActivity extends Activity {
```

Comment: INTENT_ACTION_SELECT_DIR to select a file?

Comment: Where should I put this?

Comment: You put it! But that does not look like a good idea. See the first line of the code you posted.

Comment: Oh it was so sily of me... Thanx for showing me my mistake actually I though of putting INTENT_ACTION_SELECT_FILE and then put the other one thank you!!!!!!!!

Comment: Now I expect you that you change Vassiliev's code a bit as now it does not show files if you try to select a directory. That is very annoying when you want to selectt a directory which has special content where you are after